# Update subframe of collision object?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to update the subframe of a collision object, but this gives me quite some struggles. To clarify a bit: I am simulating picking an apple. The apple is modelled as a sphere which has a subframe positioned at the spheres' center, with the z-axis always pointing upward towards the stem. To ease approach for the robot, I want to rotate the subframe around the z-axis and have one axis approximately pointing towards the robot base link. I am using ROS2 Foxy and MoveIt2 on Ubuntu 20.04, with Rviz for visualisation.

The situation is as follows:

- I spawn a sphere-shaped collision object, with a certain orientation. I also give it a subframe with the exact same orientation. This works nicely and I can plan a path using this subframe.
- After identifying the target apple, I want to rotate the subframe of the apple around its z-axis. I manage to extract the collision object and subframe information from the planning scene interface, and then do some linear algebra. This is not the problem. However, when I try to apply this subframe to the collision object again, this does not work, I can see that the path planning still uses the initial subframe.
- It is possible to remove the apple from the planning scene and create a new one with the new subframe, but that seems quite a bit of unnecessary actions for what I aim to do.

So far, I tried to update the subframe using both `object.operation = object.MOVE` and  `object.operation = object.APPEND`, but this does not rotate the frame. I also tried this with adding the current pose as well, and also with ADD, but all with no result.

```
moveit_msgs::msg::CollisionObject object;
object.header.frame_id = "base_link";
object.id = "object_name";
object.subframe_names.resize(1);
object.subframe_poses.resize(1);
object.subframe_names[0] = "middle";
object.subframe_poses[0].position.x = pos_x; 
object.subframe_poses[0].position.y = pos_y;
object.subframe_poses[0].position.z = pos_z; 
object.subframe_poses[0].orientation = tf2::toMsg(transformed_quaternion);
object.operation = object.MOVE;
psi.applyCollisionObject(object);
```

Does anyone have an idea whether this is possible and if so, how? I hope this question and information is clear enough, thanks a lot in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394126/update-subframe-of-collision-object?/) by [anonymous93348](https://answers.ros.org/users/93348/anonymous93348/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-01-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-13**:
Hi @sabine in case you don’t get a response. Consider using the MoveIt Discord channel: https://discord.com/invite/RrySut8

**Comment by [anonymous93348](https://answers.ros.org/users/93348/anonymous93348/) on 2022-01-28**:
For everyone interested: I did not find a solution to updating a subframe. However, I did manage a workaround, by keeping the subframe and sphere untouched and publishing the new frame using a TF broadcaster and using that frame for planning. This works basically the same as the planning by frame as shown in the [subframes tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/subframes_tutorial.html?highlight=subframes).

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-28**:
Great! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer from comments:

For everyone interested: I did not find a solution to updating a subframe. However, I did manage a workaround, by keeping the subframe and sphere untouched and publishing the new frame using a TF broadcaster and using that frame for planning. This works basically the same as the planning by frame as shown in the [subframes tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/subframes_tutorial.html?highlight=subframes).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0